# How to copy the contents of one Outlook folder to another Outlook Folder

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

Does anyone know how to copy the contents of one folder in Outlook to another Outlook folder in c#, or copy the contents of an Outlook folder to a SharePoint list in c#?

Answer (score 0):

To copy a folder's contents to another folder you can use the [CopyTo method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.copyto.aspx) of the Folder Interface which is part of the [Office 2010 Primary Interop Assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb652780.aspx).

There are some Folder related samples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184634.aspx) which might help get you started.